# how to query a many-to-many relationship and use Group By?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following schema and want to use `group` by to obtain the count of members by TypeName: 
[image]

I have written this query which returns all of the results:

```
Select *
from Members
join MemberType on Members.MemberID = MemberType.MemberID
join Types on Types.TypeID = MemberType.TypeID
Group by MemberType.TypeID
```

[image]

Comment: If that query works I'm assuming this is MySQL? Can you clarify _exactly_ what results you want to group by `TypeName`? Do you want just the count the number of clubs?

Comment: TypeName and count of members for each typeName, its sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by implies an aggregate function such as count, avg, min, max, etc.  The select statement of a query with a group by can contain only aggregate functions and columns represented in the group by.  Your query won't work because you are selecting ALL the columns and grouping by only one.

Based on your response - you want to have

```
select count(*), typename
from.....
group by typename
```